# You have an error in your SQL syntax check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL

Tags: model, codeigniter-2

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE ` = ''' at line 2

Thanks to support fixes in framwork codeigniter :
I run the function home/getInfo following error :
Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE ` = ''' at line 2

SELECT * WHERE ` = ''

Filename: /home/........com/models/default_model.php

Line Number: 51

```
==>> Controller  :function home/getInfo: 



function getInfo($table='',$var='',$val=''){

        $data=$this->default_model->getInfoID($table,array($var => $val));
        return $data;
    }

==> moddel default_model.php :
 function getInfoID($table,$data,$noibang='',$random='') 
    { 
      if($noibang!=""){
        foreach ($noibang as $join)
        {
        $this->db->join($join['key'], $join['where']);
        }
      }
      if($random!=""){
        $this->db->order_by($random, "random"); 
      }
        $query = $this->db->get_where($table,$data);  <-- line 51
          if($query->num_rows()!=0){
            return $query->row_array();
          }
          else{
            return FALSE;
          } 
    }
```

==> can you help me?

Comment: Change _SELECT * WHERE ` =_ to _SELECT * WHERE  =_. Remove  `

Answer (score 0):

try like this...

==>> Controller  :function home/getInfo:

```
function getInfo($table='',$var='',$val=''){

        $data=$this->default_model->getInfoID($table,array($var => $val));
        return $data;
    }

==> moddel default_model.php :
 function getInfoID($table,$data = array(),$noibang='',$random='') 
    { 
      if($noibang!=""){
        foreach ($noibang as $join)
        {
        $this->db->join($join['key'], $join['where']);
        }
      }
      if($random!=""){
        $this->db->order_by($random, "random"); 
      }
        $this->db->where($data);
        $query = $this->db->get($table);      
         if($query->num_rows()> 0){
            return $query->row_array();
          }
          else{
            return FALSE;
          } 
    }
```